# Weird issues with php://input

Tags: php, lua

I'm not sure if this is normal or not. But I'm sending a post request via lua in this game. But the post request looks like this

[image: img]

Here's my code.

```
<?php
  $file = 'place.txt';
      $post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
      echo($post_data);
      file_put_contents($file, $post_data);
?>
```

Edit: I did some testing around and found out the data is being encoded. I can decode it with fiddler but not sure what its encoded in

Comment: are you setting the `Content-type` header in lua correctly, or are you sending raw, binary data? set it to x-www-form-urlencoded, and use the `$_POST` array instead would be my suggestion

Comment: Please show your lua side code as well.

Comment: The encoding type is gzip